# TFS 2017 - [ProjectName].setParameters.xml with powershell

Tags: powershell, token, release, webdeploy

I create a zip Package in my build then i deploy it to a diffrent machine i am pasing few Parameters in my parameters.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <parameters>   
        <parameter name="WebSiteUserName" description="Please enter the username" defaultvalue="__WebSiteUserName__" tags="">
        <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@key='WebSiteUserName']/@value">
        </parameterentry>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="WebSiteUserPassword" description="Please enter the password" defaultvalue="__UserPassword__" tags="">
        <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@key='WebSiteUserPassword']/@value">
        </parameterentry>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="WebSiteDomain" description="Domiain" defaultvalue="__Domain__" tags="">
        <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='WebSiteDomain']/@value">
    </parameterentry>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
    </parameters>
```

Then i run a powershell script

```
param(
    [string]$paramsFilePath
)

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Entering script Replace-SetParameters.ps1"
Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Path to SetParametersFile: {0}" -f $paramsFilePath)

# get the environment variables
$vars = Get-ChildItem -path env:*

# read in the setParameters file
$contents = Get-Content -Path $paramsFilePath

# perform a regex replacement
$newContents = "";

$contents  | % {
    $line = $_
    if ($_ -match "__(\w+[\.\w+]*)__") {
        $setting = Get-ChildItem -path env:* | ? { $_.Name -eq $Matches[1]  }
        while ($setting) {
            Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Replacing key {0} with value from environment" -f $setting.Name)
            $line = $_ -replace "__(\w+[\.\w+]*)__", $setting.Value
        }
    }
    $newContents += $line + [Environment]::NewLine
}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Overwriting SetParameters file with new values"
Set-Content $paramsFilePath -Value $newContents
Write-Verbose " Assigning Parameters"



Write-Verbose -Verbose "Exiting script Replace-SetParameters.ps1"
```

It will go through the parameters file and replace the parameters token with the enviromental variable.

In my setParamaters.xml file The WebSiteUsername only gets changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/SomeWebsite" />
  <setParameter name="WebSiteUserName" value="username" />
  <setParameter name="WebSiteUserPassword" value="__UserPassword__" />
  <setParameter name="Web.config Connection String" value="SomeValueForConnection" />
</parameters>
```

I dont know why this is happening. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to get the password from a TFS release definition environment.

You can´t access hidden fields with

```
$vars = Get-ChildItem -path env:secretVariable
```

There is a way but that´s only works in the context of a TFS VNext build or release extension.

In your case the only possibility of access is to set the variable as a script argument like this:

```
-paramsFilePath $(paramsFilePath) -password $(secretVariable)
```

In your script add the parameter like

```
param(
   [string]$paramsFilePath,
   [string]$password 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have tried it before no luck :(

Comment: I am sure that it works. I will try it later. Currently I have no access to a TFS.

Comment: I checked it and it worked like expected. Use Write-Verbose $password to take a show the value of the variable

Comment: Then maybe i have a problem somewhere else;( thanks for the answer anyway.